# How do I undelete a file after git rm and pushing to github?

Tags: git, github, repository, undelete

I recently cloned a repository on my local machine and then did a git remove on one of the files and pushed those changes back to the github repository. My question is how do I restore that file back on the original github repository?

Answer (score 34):

If you can find a previous commit `abcd` that has the deleted file, then you can use

> git checkout abcd file-to-restore

to restore it. You'll need to commit the file again.

Comment: I had to add a ^ to the commit to get this to work - idea from an answer below. so git checkout abcd^ file-to-restore

Answer (score 33):

Let's assume the file "undelete.sh" was accidentally removed.

Then get the hash of the commit in which this file is deleted:

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- undelete.sh
```

Which gives you the hash of the deletion:

```
ae85c23372a8a45b788ed857800b3b424b1c15f8
```

Now you can checkout the version of the file before the deletion:

```
git checkout ae85c23372a8a45b788ed857800b3b424b1c15f8^ -- undelete.sh
```

And you should have the file back. You may add, commit and push it to the repository.

([source](https://tqdev.com/2019-script-to-undelete-all-files-in-git))

Answer (score 5):

Other solutions did not worked for me. This is how I did it.

This is how I get the commit hash. (*Copied from above*)

```
git rev-list -n 1 HEAD -- src/main/java/runner/Main.java
```

which gave me

```
6009ff608bc580cf38baf5fa67e232c8bd20c5a7
```

And, this is how I restored it.

```
git checkout 6009ff608bc580cf38baf5fa67e232c8bd20c5a7~1 src/main/java/runner/Main.java
```

Comment: this is the only approach which worked for me. Not sure why the ones with more upvotes didn't. My lack of knowledge is probably the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

1.If the deleted file is in your `.gitignore`,then you can remove it in `.gitignore` and `git add`  it again.

2.You can just use `git reset 'commit id contains your deleted file'` then merge and push it again.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `git reset HEAD~` and then use `git checkout -- <filename>` to restore deleted files.

Comment: You are assuming the deletion was made in previous commit, what if it was deleted long time ago.